# Update using three tables in netezza

Tags: netezza

I am trying to avoid a co-related sub query which in turn made me to update from three different tables and I am not quite sure how to do updates from three tables using netezza.

```
update stemp
set maxi = a.marks
from stemp
left join
sd696 sd 
where st.id = sd.id
left join
(select id,MAX(marks) marks from sm696 group by ID) a 
where a.id = sd.id;
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you require joins in UPDATEs, the joins are specified implicitly in a comma separated FROM clause (without specifying the UPDATEd table again), with the JOIN criteria being specified in the WHERE clause.

Your UPDATE would look something like this:

```
UPDATE stemp
SET maxi = a.marks
FROM sd696 sd,
   (
      SELECT id,
         MAX(marks) marks
      FROM sm696
      GROUP BY ID
   )
   a
WHERE stemp.id = sd.id
AND a.id       = sd.id;
```